# Is is possible to achieve reliable BIOS updating using DELL Command | Update command line options in silent mode?

Tags: command-line, bios, updates

We use the CLI (dcu-cli.exe) of DELL Command | Update to update our DELL Latitude and OptiPlex machines in silent mode. Driver and app updates do work perfectly but BIOS updates are often left out. They probably need a system restart instead of the usual shutdown/power up cycle. Is it still possible to achieve reliable BIOS updating without user intervention?

Comment: I found that it does work together with the Windows 10 WSUS "update and shutdown orange dot" shutdown option in case windows does a reboot and shutdown. This option can easily be recognized by the users. Is it maybe possible to set this state after the DCU update?

Comment: Updates to the question should be [edit]ed in, not posted as comments.